# Declare the same identifier as const variable and member function

Tags: c++, variables, scope, declaration

I have wrote the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
const int N = 5;
class X
{
  public:
  int array[N];
  void foo()
  {
     std::cout << "array size:"<<sizeof(array)/N << std::endl;   
  }
  enum
 {
   N = 3    
  };
};

int main()
{
  X x;
  x.foo();
}
```

The aforementioned code does not compile with GCC:

```
<source>:13:8: error: declaration of 'N' [-fpermissive]
    N = 3
        ^
<source>:2:11: error: changes meaning of 'N' from 'const int N' [-fpermissive]
 const int N = 5;
           ^
```

From my point  in compile time the array is defined as an array of five integers and N is defined as 5.  How the compiler resolved the name declaration of variables?

Comment: Compiles on Clang, not on GCC. You should put the full error message in the question.

Comment: Compiles on MSVC 2018.

Comment: `std::cout << "array size:"<<sizeof(array)/N << std::endl;` --> `std::cout << "array size:" << std::size(array) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the declaration `int array[N];`.

According to [[basic.scope.class]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#2):

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

In the context of the declaration, `N` is resolved to refer to `::N`, but in the completed scope of `X` (all members are visible now), `N` is resolved to refer to the enumerator `X::N`, so the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.

Answer (score 6):

Inside the scope of member functions (even those defined inline), the class is considered complete<sup>1</sup>. As such, using `N` there must use the member enumerator. And its value must be 3.

But, that is not the case when declaring class member data. At that point (when specifying `array`), the class is not made to be considered complete. So `N` can only refer to what was seen previously, which means it must be the global constant.

Clang accepts it, but emits `6` (`sizeof(int) * 5 / 3`). GCC (8) doesn't, but it isn't really invalid code. It's just error prone. The way to make better defined would be to move the enumerator to before the array is defined

```
enum { N = 3 };
int array[N];
```

... or if we don't, then we can use scope resolution to refer to the "correct N"

```
sizeof(array) / ::N
```

Rearranging the class definition would be better, since it will not still remain error prone (we can forget to use the qualified `::N`).

---

1: From the latest C++ standard draft

> [**[class.mem]/6**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#6)
>
> A complete-class context of a class is a
>
> - function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - default argument ([dcl.fct.default]),
> - noexcept-specifier,
> - contract condition ([dcl.attr.contract]), or
> - default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class.

Comment: I'm confused. You say that in the declarator of the array, the class is not complete. Okay. But then you say that defining the enum before the array makes the array use the enum value and not the constant. Why?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Because it was previously defined, and doesn't depend on being in a complete-class context to shadow the global constant.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - Though I did fudge up the pharsing. Should be *"when defining class member data"*. Fixed now

Comment: I can't get g++ to complain with `-pedantic-errors` in 7.3.0, not even after adding `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @molbdnilo - What Rakete1111 said. As a matter of fact, it complains even without pedantic falgs.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why isn't a value of an enum part of the class? So it's like technically a member, but also not really?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - It is a member. It's just that it isn't looked up in the declarators of member data as though the class was complete, only in their initializers, if those are present. It's... unfortunate.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ooh I see. Thanks! :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Now I can't sleep until I've figured out why the 7.3 in Cygwin doesn't mind it.

Answer (score 2):

In the line

```
int array[N];
```

`N` is the global `N`.

Inside the function `foo()`, the `N` is the one defined in the `enum`.

Inside the definition of `foo()` the definition of the class is used to resolve names. However, in the declaration of a member variable, only the declarations up to that line is used to resolve names.

If you change your class to

```
class X
{
   public:
      enum
      {
         N = 3    
      };

      int array[N];
      void foo()
      {
         std::cout << "array size:"<<sizeof(array)/N << std::endl;   
      }
};
```

Then, the `N` used to define `array` is the one defined in th `enum`.

**PS**
This is useful for understanding the language but, please, never ever use such coding style in real world applications.